# Why if I pass a @Res() response to the service, it won't execute?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

Tell me pls, why if I pass a `@Res() response` to the service, it won't execute? That is, if the code is executed successfully (doesn't get into the catch) the return in Postman loads endlessly.

Controller:

```
@Controller({
  path: 'erc',
  version: '1',
})
export class ErcControllerV1 {
  constructor(private readonly web3Service: Web3Service) {}

  @Post('/balance')
  @HttpCode(200)
  balance(@Body(new ValidationPipe()) balanceWeb3Dto: BalanceWeb3Dto, @Res() response) {
    return this.web3Service.balance(
      process.env.CHAIN_LINK_ETH,
      balanceWeb3Dto,
      response,
    );
  }
}
```

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class Web3Service {
  async balance(chainLink, balanceWeb3Dto, response) {
    try {
      let balance;
      const web3 = new Web3(chainLink);
      const validateAddress = new Web3().utils.isAddress(
        balanceWeb3Dto.address,
      );

      if (validateAddress) {
        const getBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance(balanceWeb3Dto.address);

        balance = parseFloat(
          web3.utils.fromWei(getBalance.toString(), 'ether'),
        );

        return {
          status: true,
          data: balance,
        };
      } else {
        return response.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).json({
          status: false,
          message: 'Incorrect address',
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw new HttpException(
        {
          message: e.message,
        },
        HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
        {
          cause: e,
        },
      );
    }
  }
}
```

If the code falls into `catch()` or `else`, then the response is loaded.

But if I remove the `@Res() response` from the controller and from the service and service parameters, then the return loads successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `@Res()` [as the docs mention](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#library-specific-approach) you are in charge of handling the response. The only exception to that is if an exception is thrown and handled by an [exception filter](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters)

Comment: I have an exception filter. Because of this I can't use `@Res()`?

Comment: That's not what I said. I said if you use `@Res()` you must send the response yourself. The only case where you don't have to do `res.send()` yourself is if an exception is caught via an exception filter. Notice how in your `catch` you `throw` a new error and still get a response, that's because the exception filter sends it. However, in your happy path (the if, not the else) you `return object` and never get a response; that's because Nest is expecting you to `res.send()` it